# Removing the underlines from menu key words

Tags: 11.10

If I click on a menu at the top of the screen in, say, Gimp, and navigate through the options, then key words - or rather, key *letters* - suddenly become underlined. My guess is that this is keyboard shortcut access.

It's a bit untidy and not something I use, though, and I'm wondering if there's a way to turn the underlining off. Like, perhaps, in DConf or something.

Or is this not possible?

Comment: I assume that this is not possible?

Comment: Those are built into the application(s) themselves.. This is a design feature of the application developer and should be a question to them. Afaik making a change like this system-wide is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to be possible on a system wide level.

The underlines are called accelerators and they're implemented at design time. The only way to get rid of them would be to change the actual code of an application to remove the accelerator.